# How to load CSS files to HTML file in Django...?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm learning Django framework.I tried to link my CSS file into HTML file in Django but it not working.
I use `{% load staticfiles %}` keyword also...
I'm using Pycharm community IDE....how to solve this? What is the problem in this...???

This is the HTML file content:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {% static 'music/style.css' %} "/>

{% if all_album %}
  <ul>
    {% for album in all_album %}
        <li><a href="{%url 'music:detail' album.id %}">{{album.title}}</a> 
         </li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endif %}
```

This is CSS file content:

```
body{
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Have you placed `style.css` file inside the `static/music/` folder?

Comment: Maybe it is woking but you don't notice that because the `background: white;` is a default value. Try usign `background: red;` to see if it really doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check if the css file is loaded first.

Comment: I think you should put `/` before music  `{% static '/music/style.css' %}` to make it absolute path